# JBoss twiddle - invoking many operations

Tags: jboss

I have to invoke many operations via twiddle at one time. Isn't executing twiddle.sh many times slow? How can I speed it up?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I googled over some pages, but none of them helped me. Many of them said that I have to execute twiddle.sh for each command, but this approach executes java machine each time.